# Count Number of Occurrences of Object in List

Tags: python, count

I have a .CSV file with LSAT answers from a website as such:

```
"Test","Question","Section","Question Type","Your Answer","Correct Answer"    
"PT 62","2: 1","LR","Best Principle for Example","D","D"    
"PT 62","2: 2","LR","Strengthen","E","E"    
"PT 62","2: 3","LR","Direct Logic Link","B","B"

... repeat 1,000x
```

**I want to start deriving data from this .CSV such that I can figure out the percentage (or how many) questions of "Question Type" I have gotten correct.**

I have consulted the Python manual, many forum questions of similar types, and a lot of .count answers, but none seem to fit what I'm trying to do.

```
import csv
import itertools
import json
from collections import Counter

file = open('C:/Users/Kenny/Downloads/logicReasoning.csv')
reader = csv.reader(file)
data = list(reader)

masterList = []
questionTypes =[]

for row in data:
    masterList.append(row[3])
    for x in masterList:
        c = Counter(x)
        masterList.count(x)
        print("total "+x+":", masterList.count(x))
```

Output

```
total Justify: 28

total Definition: 28

total Most Similar in Flawed Reasoning: 14

total Resolve Discrepancy: 24

etc, for each question type.
```

The above code prints out a list of the "Question Type", plus the number of times it was counted in masterList, **for each and every time the Question Type occurs**

Such that, 'Justify 28' is printed 28 times, one time for each time it occurs in the CSV file.

I would like only for 'Justify' to be printed once, with it's total count in the CSV file.

Then I would be re-doing the same code for 'Question Type' such that I make a new, empty list, and append each instance only if it is correct - given as:

```
if row[4] == row[5]:
    correctList.append(row[3])
```

Would this be a correct way of counting total questions by Question Type, and counting total questions correct by Question Type, such that I may then derive percentages and other data?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to start deriving data from this .CSV such that I can figure out the percentage (or how many) questions of "Question Type" I have gotten correct.

Tasks like these are very easy to do with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), I encourage you to try out the library. I will give you a short demo of what you can do with a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

**Demo**

```
import pandas as pd

demo = pd.DataFrame(
        [['A', 'one', 'two'],
         ['B', 'foo', 'bar'],
         ['A', 'fizz', 'fizz'],
         ['A', 'buzz', 'buzz']],
        columns=['Question Type', 'Your Answer', 'Correct Answer'])

print(demo)
print()

demo['is_correct'] = demo['Your Answer'] == demo['Correct Answer']

print(demo)
print()

correct_answers = demo.groupby(['Question Type', 'is_correct']).size()

print(correct_answers)
```

**Output**

```
  Question Type Your Answer Correct Answer
0             A         one            two
1             B         foo            bar
2             A        fizz           fizz
3             A        buzz           buzz

  Question Type Your Answer Correct Answer  is_correct
0             A         one            two       False
1             B         foo            bar       False
2             A        fizz           fizz        True
3             A        buzz           buzz        True

Question Type  is_correct
A              False         1
               True          2
B              False         1
dtype: int64
```

In your actual code, you can read the csv file with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv) instead of manually typing in the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) initialization.

Comment: really cool use of Pandas here, for sure will be trying this out. I personally have yet to explore Pandas but I consistently see people utilizing it

Comment: Hey man hope you see this, but I'm having a little trouble calculating % correct sorted by 'Question Type' -----

df['is_correct'] = df['Your Answer'] == df['Correct Answer'] //////
correct_answers = df.groupby(['Question Type', 'is_correct']).size()

----- this returns a new colum, 'is_correct', with True/False counted values. How can I then extract from this data the % of questions I got correct?

Comment: for x in correct_answers: /////
    if df.groupby(['Question Type', 'is_correct'] == True://////
        df['percentCorrect'] = df['is_correct', True] // qTypeTotal ----- returns ValueError "the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), a.all()"

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('lsat.csv') as fp:
    for row in csv.reader(fp):
        counter[row[3]] += 1

print(counter)
print(list(counter.keys()))
print(counter['Strengthen'])
```

Comment: edit: this seems to print the counter 28+ times, will tweak

Comment: That would surprise me: there are only 3 print functions.